# Final steps for moving Wordpress site to another server

Tags: wordpress

Ive read many other threads here and also guides as this is my first time moving a Wordpress site to another server and I think Ive done everything correct so far but not sure.

So far Ive done the following:

- Backed up WP files and moved them to public_html of new server and ip
- Created a new Mysql db along with user and imported the old DB
- Checked the imported DB in phpmyadmin and everything seems to be
  there Changed wp-config file to the new db details
- Also defined the site url in wp-config like so:

  define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.example.com' );

Finally Ive changed my local hosts file to the following:

```
new.ip.here    example.com
```

when I visit example.com it seems to redirect to www.example.com which I believe should be my site as it is still on the old/current server.

I logged in to WP anyway and did a test post but the post then appeared on the site on the old server which I guess confirms what I said above?

When I run the following ping commands I get these results though

```
ping example.com - new ip returned
ping www.example.com - old ip returned
```

Have I done everything correct so far and if so how can I test the site on the new server if its redirecting me away?

thanks

Comment: In your local host file can you add the IP address to point to www.example.com. See if that works?

Comment: You also need to change old urls in your database to new urls in your database [check this link](https://madebydenis.com/manually-migrate-locally-developed-wordpress-site-to-a-live-server/) for explanation.

Comment: I added the domain with 'www' and without in hosts file and that seemed to work, I had another problem though which I will put in the answer below

Comment: @dingo_d - thanks, why will my urls change though? I read that article and not sure if I need to do that, the domain is the same and all urls should stay the same and they seem to be ok now when testing it?

Comment: If the domain is the same, and the urls don't change, then you don't need to true. I was under the impression that you are transfering from local to live version :)

Comment: np, I actually need to do that with another site soon anyway so that guide will come in handy! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something I do each time to be sure that I didn't forget anything is to search for my old domain name in all the base and change to the new one. Because sometimes there are hard links in posts or pages...

If you made your own theme, verify there too... Sometimes people make this mistake to put hard links...

For your host files, this will work only for YOUR computer. Check if the DNS are correct instead. then the changes ill apply to everyone.

Comment: OK thanks for our answer, what do you mean by 'base' though?

Comment: Also, about DNS, I havent changed those over and its still the DNS for the old host, so how can I effectively check that the site is ok before I change the DNS over?

Comment: By base I meant the DB :) In phpmyadmin, just select your new DB and do a hole DB search for your old website url (without www in case of...)
Also you should verify that the data were correctly imported just by checking the options table for example and see if the blog name is correct (for example). BTW, if you can access on the new website after doing everything, browsing the site, create a page or two, and everything is OK, then you're done :)

Comment: Modifying your hosts is the good way to test while you have not set your DNS :-) You're OK for that !

Answer (score 0):

I had created the new mysql db and user in ssh and not cpanel, even though Id checked the permissions and everything seemed in order when I logged into mysql admin in cpanel for this ip it showed no dbs and users at all for that account, strangely though the db I had imported was there in phpmyadmin.

I created a brand new db & user in mysql admin and then used both the domain plus with 'www' in my hosts file and it looks like I can see the site on my new server now and done a test post which only appears there so I think this has fixed it.